# Blank pages in rails 3 no error

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, rspec

I ran into an issue where I kept getting blank pages on my dev machine even though the server looked like it was serving up the pages fine.

I'd reload the page and same thing--just a blank page for any page I went to. I googled around and people had some solutions from 2010 that pointed to stale sessions and deleting those session files but this didn't solve it for me.

finally after much git sleuthing through my old code I found that this line in my gemfile was the culprit.

```
group :development, :test do
  gem 'rspec-rails'
  gem 'factory_girl_rails'
  gem 'rspec_multi_matchers'
end
```

changed to

```
group :development, :test do
  gem 'rspec-rails'
  gem 'factory_girl_rails'
end
```

I removed rspec_multi_matchers, did a bundle install and everything works again. i have no clue why this was causing this issue. Would love to know if someone has an idea why.

Comment: Do you have do..end in your tests?  There is a warning on their page that says "Note the use of brackets ‘{ … }’ instead of ‘do … end’ this is necessary because ‘do .. end’ does not bind strongly enough"

Comment: ah maybe thats it. embarrassingly, I kind of just skimmed a tutorial on rspec and stuck it in there with the intention of coming back later to understand it better.

Comment: I will add it as an answer for the reference

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do you have `do..end` in your tests?

There is a warning on their page that says

> Note the use of brackets ‘{ … }’ instead of ‘do … end’ this is
>   necessary because ‘do .. end’ does not bind strongly enough